# How to start a application as admin from the Windows 7 Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

As the question says how would I start a application as admin when using Windows 7's search box. This must be done using the keyboard only , I tried Shift + Enter and ctrl + Enter , both don't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit Windows-key, type some program name, Ctrl-Shift-Enter, confirm UAC - Voilà! This is my *favorite* feature of Windows Vista/7!
I *never* go looking in the All Programs menu anymore! :)

Answer (score 6):

It's a command in the context menu, so just go to the application you want to start using the arrow buttons, and press the "context-menu" button:

[image]

Then go down (using the arrows again) to the "run as administrator" command and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Lol i guess that could work , was hoping for a cleaner way of doing it :)

Answer (score 3):

In Vista, the keyboard shortcut for run as administrator is Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

I would hope/assume they didn't change it for Windows 7