# Run cmd.exe in Administrator mode without explorer.exe

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer, administrator

I've recently had trouble with explorer.exe not working.  I found a possible solution [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-ultimate-x64-explorerexe-crashes-and/aec190b3-3a29-4a00-97c3-4573d1ff64c5), using [sfc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833).  The problem is that I cannot "right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator", since explorer.exe does not work for even a second without crashing.  I tried to use the [runas command](https://superuser.com/a/74565/233743) to open cmd as administrator, but I get an error 1327 because I have a blank password.

My question is, is there any *other* way to run cmd.exe with admin privileges?  If not, is there any way to run sfc.exe *without* admin privileges?  If not, does anyone have solution to my original problem of explorer.exe stopping and restarting ad nauseam?

Comment: Are you attempting to start windows in safe mode?

Comment: No, I still have the same problem in safe mode

Comment: You may find some answers [here](http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/462174/win-r-runs-as-administrator), and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/44472/how-to-start-a-application-as-admin-from-the-windows-7-start-menu).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a simple solution that I can't believe I overlooked.  Just open Task Manager, click "Show processes from all users", then click **Continue** to get Task Manager with Administrative Privileges.  From there, go to **File** > **New Task** > `cmd` > **OK**, which will now open *with* admin privileges.  From there I was able to get `sfc` to work just fine.

Comment: Another solution: In Task Manager, press the **Ctrl** button while clicking *New Task*, and it will automatically open the Command Prompt as the Admin

Comment: No. Holding Ctrl will just open cmd in the current user's security context not as an admin. When I tried this and did a whoami it return my username.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any other way to run cmd.exe with admin privileges?

Yes, restart your computer in safe mode and log in as the "administrator" user, he normally only shows up when you are logging in to safe mode.

---

> If not, is there any way to run sfc.exe without admin privileges?

SFC requires administrator privileges, however you can remove the drive and run sfc.exe on another computer that you can run software as administrator, you will need to use the arguments `/OFFBOOTDIR` and `/OFFWINDIR` to point at the drive letter of the attached drive.

```
sfc /scannow /OFFBOOTDIR=d:\ /OFFWINDIR=d:\windows
```

That is what you would type on the other computer if the new attached drive showed up as the `D:` drive.

---

> If not, does anyone have solution to my original problem of
>   explorer.exe stopping and restarting ad nauseam?

Your last option is use the [System Recover Options menu](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-happened-to-the-recovery-console) and try rolling back to a restore point. (it's not SFC but it may fix the problem)

Answer (score 0):

try a new profile? it could be one user account is trashed?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I couldn't use Task Manager.

So if you have permissions, you can try opening `msconfig.exe`, in tools tab find `Command Prompt` and click run. This will bypass the UAC prompt and run cmd in privileged mode.

Answer (score -1):

cmd.exe is in windows\system32. if you go there you can always press the right click button to open it as admin

task manager - new task - search - go to \windows\system32\ and find cmd.exe - press right mouse button - run as admin

:D

Comment: This requires explorer in a working state, which is not the case according to OP.