# Is there any way to open cmd in windows 7 if the explorer.exe has been already disabled (which means you cant use the start menu)

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Is there any way to open `cmd.exe` in Windows 7 if `explorer.exe` has been disabled (which means you can't use the Start Menu)

Comment: Welcome to SU! Did you try Googling your question?  I did and found [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/612030/run-cmd-exe-in-administrator-mode-without-explorer-exe) on Superuser.com

Comment: Use windows explorer string.

Answer (score 15):

Yes.  Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and bring up Task Manager.  Then on the File menu, hit New Task...  Type `cmd` in the box and BAM! -- a command prompt window.  Although, you could also just respawn the shell by typing `explorer` in the box too.

Comment: A faster but little known shortcut key for accessing Task Manager in Windows 7 is: Ctrl + Shift + Esc. Ctrl + Alt + Del may not get to Task Manager in one step in Windows 7.

Comment: or right click the task bar and select Task Manager there.

Comment: @jwenting right clicking on task bar won't work if explorer is dead or disabled

Comment: That gives you a cmd, but it is not in elevated mode. Hence pretty useless.

Comment: OP did not say he needed an elevated prompt.  If he did, he could use the browse button to find cmd.exe.  The Run as Administrator option is on the right-click menu from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot start Explorer, or Explorer's run box has been disabled, and Task Manager's run box has also been disabled, but you can still use Word (or Excel &c.) you can often open the macro editor and use VBA to start any executable you want.

Comment: Just to complete the answer. The needed command would be `shell "cmd"`

Comment: Or you could simply use the "open file" dialog

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

type cmd -> bam you got a black screen

Comment: i dont understand how this is not the answer to this quiestion

Comment: might be because i hate windows .. :D ..thanks for the info BTW

Comment: If you feel it answers the question perhaps you can explain **why** it does so? For example, where exactly are you when you type ctrl+r? And how does a black screen help?

Comment: ohhh ithought this is a social site people understand words ...  i think i should be using this site very professionally :D

Comment: @DavidPostill: The black screen helps because it is the command window (commonly referred to as a lack screen). I'm wondering if win+r was meant instead of ctrl+r though since I don't think the latter would do much (well, except refresh my browser window, for example).

Comment: That's better. Now your answer makes more sense :)

Comment: @Aura Does this actually work if explorer is dead?

Comment: @Taemyr I just personally tested it on Windows 7, and Win + R does not work when explorer is dead. It would appear that Ctrl + Shift + Esc is the quickest route, via accessing the Task Manager then creating a new task there for cmd.

Comment: Win+R is a shortcut for the start menu and then the run command. Since explorer.exe is not running, the start menu is not available hence this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to task manager via **Ctrl + Alt + Esc** and run a new task.

Type `iexplore`- IE will open then after type

```
file:///c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

in the address bar, press Enter. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to promote this to an answer (rather than a comment on the currently-highest-voted, but not-actually-the-best-way-to-do-this answer):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Task Manager. On the Task Manager window's File menu, choose "Run new task". Type `cmd` in the box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or press 'OK'. Alternatively, if you think Explorer would be OK once it's restarted, instead of typing `cmd` in the box, type `explorer`.

(In general, if your system has gotten to the point where Windows Explorer has crashed, you don't want to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> unless you're OK with your computer misinterpreting you and restarting itself. This is especially true if, in the chain of events that led to Explorer crashing, you perhaps have already given the three-finger salute a few times. In this sense, the Task Manager key combination is "safer".)